# NgSpice error: unknown subckt

Tags: ngspice

I am have defined a subcircuit header as:

```
.SUBCKT RELAY_SPDT_BHV coila coilb no nc com T_make=20mSec T_break=10mSec I_pull=35ma I_drop=25ma R_coil=100 L_coil=5mH R_open=100MEG R_close=.05
```

and I am calling it as:

```
X1 6 1 4 7 8 RELAY_SPDT_BHV 6 1 4 7 8
```

however, I got error:

```
Error: unknown subckt: x1 6 1 4 7 8 relay_spdt_bhv 6 1 4 7 8
```

but I already successfully created another subcircuit for a `pot` as:

```
.SUBCKT pot 1 T 2 VALUE=1K SET=0.5
```

and called it as:

```
X2 15 16 17 POT VALUE=1000 SET=0.005
```

and it worked perfectly, so why it doesn't work for `RELAY_SPDT_BHV` above?

Comment: Like @jonk advised yesterday: get LTspice. You can get familiar how the netlist should be composed using their GUI. Make a subcircuit in LTspice and 'View netlist'. Compare it to your netlist.

Comment: Regarding the error, Read The Fabulous Manual about subcircuits and carefully compare your pot subckt with your relay subckt. You'll find there = a difference...

Comment: Yea, thanks I tried to, and it worked for me in pot as above, I will try LTSpice for Mac and see, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found it, I had to call it as:

```
X1 6 1 4 7 8 RELAY_SPDT_BHV
```

without passing ports after `RELAY_SPDT_BHV`